# Is there a web app that allows browsing a remote source control repository?

Tags: webapp-rec

There are many open-source projects hosted online, and some of them offer a very convenient "browse" service, which allows me to browse their source code using a graphical interface in my browser and thus take a glimpse at a few interesting areas without the need for even having the source control program installed, let alone firing it up and connecting.

Some other projects, however, do not offer that service, but do allow anonymous access into their repositories.

**My question is, are there some web services that can be fed the address of a different, remote repository, and then allow me to browse the code** as if that browsing service was offered by the original site. I am especially interested in solution that can display **SVN** repositories, but would like to hear about solutions for other repository types as well.

**EDIT:** since so far I got 5 answers that do not answer my question, I'll try to clarify myself. I'm not looking for a software that I install locally, nor am I the owner of the code repository. I'm looking for an *existing web service* that allows me to browse a repository which is hosted somewhere else, not in the same place as that service. I guess there's just no such service available at this time.

Comment: As of your clarification, I'd have to agree - There must be no such service. To me it doesn't even make sense for anyone to create a web service that browse repository else where. Maybe you should just go with launchpad as Don Kirby advised right below. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/is-there-a-web-app-that-allows-browsing-a-remote-source-control-repository/7387#7387

Answer (score 0):

It's not a web app, but if you have [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) installed on your computer you can just use the built in [Repo-browser](http://wsmoak.net/subversion/demo/tsvn-repo-browser.html) to explore the source tree. Otherwise you could always setup one of the many [web](http://www.sventon.org/) [based](http://www.websvn.info/download/) [SVN](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/03/sventon-a-nice-subversion-repository-browser.html) browsers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) allows you to do this.

Assembla.com offers [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) as well as the ability to display your svn repository in a web browser.
[image: SVN on Assembla in a Web Browser]

Another solution (but not for svn for Mercurial) is Mercurial itself, from which a web server can be started.  The easiest way to todo this is using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) and selecting Web Server from the menu:

[image: TortoiseHg Web Server]
<sub>(source: [nimblecoder.com](http://www.nimblecoder.com/blog/Images/nimblecoder_com/blog/WindowsLiveWriter/UsingMercurialwithVirtualMachines_8112/tortoisehgcontextmenuwebserver.png))</sub>

Finally then you'll be able to access it in your browser (the default port for this is 8000):

[image: Mecurial in a browser]

Answer (score 0):

Launchpad allows you to [import another repository](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Imports) from several formats, including Bazaar and Subversion. You could import the repository you're interested in, and then browse the copy on launchpad. Other code hosting services may have similar import features.

Launchpad also allows you to [*mirror*](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/MirroredBranches) another Bazaar repository, so you would automatically get any updates. I couldn't find any services that do this for Subversion.

This meets your criteria of not installing anything on your workstation, but I suspect it's still more effort than you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), now ok this is software that you have to install on a web server somewhere but if you're not interested in hosting it yourself, you could always find somewhere that would.

This allows you to browse source code from a variety of open source SCMs (eg SVN, mercurial, git) by creating a project and setting the appropriate details for the remote repo.

Its typically meant for you to browse your own repo, but there's nothing that stops it from browsing someone else's as long as you have the necessary access credentials.

Trac also does this, but again, you have to host an instance of it. Trac also requires you to set up an instance for each remote repository (ie you can only have 1 project per trac instance) but you can put several links to repositories into a single project - if you're tracking many different remote repos, this would probably become messy. You can create many projects in a single instance of Redmine.

There is no 'import' required, so you will always see the latest changes as you browse the projects, and you'll see them in their 'native' format so a git repo will look like a git repo, and not an imported one.

For self-hosting, a lot of website providers will give you a control panel that will let you install apps like redmine with 1-click.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any personal experience with it, but I've come across Fisheye.

http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/